# If the function $g: R\rightarrow R$ is periodic, then $a_n=g(n)$ is periodic.

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

If the function $g: R\rightarrow R$ is periodic, then $a_n=g(n)$ is periodic. Is the converse true? Give a proof or counterexample.

Comment: Is $\sin(n)$ periodic??

Comment: This is false: $\sin n$ is *not* periodic. It's dense in $[-1,1]$ instead.

Comment: As for the converse: $g$ can do whatever you want on the non-integers.

Answer (score 2):

Both implications are false. For the statement itself consider @Bernard's comment: $sin(x)$ has trancendental period length, so that the period does not show in $\mathbb{N}$.

---

As one of many counterexamples for the converse, consider the non-periodic function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{N} \\ 
x & \mbox{else} \end{cases}$$

that becomes periodic (even constant) when restricted to $\mathbb{N}$.